# QuickTime add-ons? How to tell what's needed?

Tags: quicktime

I've been chatting on [Chatzy](http://www.chatzy.com) via Firefox on the Mac lately, and every time I go there I get told that I need to update QuickTime components. Here's the dialog that comes up:

[image: QuickTime additional software required]

It then links me to [this site](http://www.apple.com/quicktime/resources/components.html?os=OSX&ctype=705ffd5&csubtype=bfffce7e), which offers a range of addons. However, there is no indication *which* of these things I need to run the page. I don't want to install *all* the extensions, obviously, but I would like to get the one I need. Is there any way to tell what's lacking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally [Perian](http://perian.org/) will cover most of your needs. Codecs are generally loaded on an "as needed" basis so you will be fine even if you install all of them. Note though that some of the older codecs listed may be PPC-only if they are really old and won't work on Lion.

[Flip4Mac WMV](http://www.flip4mac.com/wmv.htm) is another good one, it is the official QT component for all of Microsoft's formats.

Answer (score 1):

[Perian](http://perian.org/) is frequently chosen, for being complete and suitable. A [lot of people](http://www.cultofmac.com/41856/50-mac-essentials-4-perian/) say it's one of those things you should put on every new Mac. VLC has browser plugins, but I've never noticed Perian not handling everything (not sure I would know, neither are bloated).